# Asserted data is different

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm learning Prolog on my own. I have a text file which looks like this:

```
table("0","Nicosia 2013 VulkÃ  Bianco  (Etna)","Italy","White Blend","14","Kerin Oâ€™Keefe","87").
table("1","Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red (Douro)","Portugal","Portuguese Red","15","Roger Voss","87").
table("2","Rainstorm 2013 Pinot Gris (Willamette Valley)","US","Pinot Gris","14","Paul Gregutt","87").
table("3","St. Julian 2013 Reserve Late Harvest Riesling (Lake Michigan Shore)","US","Riesling","13","Alexander Peartree","87").
```

I have 400 lines and I want to assert these in prolog. I tried out a few options and this code is the last one:

```
load_file_data(File) :-
    open(File, read, Stream),
    repeat,
    read(Stream, Term),
    (   Term = end_of_file
    ->  true
    ;   assert(Term),
        fail
    ),
    close(Stream).
```

This and a few other versions assert, but not the way I expected it to be. This is how the asserted facts look:

```
table([48], [78, 105, 99, 111, 115, 105, 97, 32, 50, 48, 49, 51, 32, 86, 117, 108, 107, 195, 402, 194, 160, 32, 66, 105, 97, 110, 99, 111, 32, 32, 40, 69, 116, 110, 97, 41], [73, 116, 97, 108, 121], [87, 104, 105, 116, 101, 32, 66, 108, 101, 110, 100], [49, 52], [75, 101, 114, 105, 110, 32, 79, 195, 162, 226, 8218, 172, 226, 8222, 162, 75, 101, 101, 102, 101], [56, 55]). 

table([49], [81, 117, 105, 110, 116, 97, 32, 100, 111, 115, 32, 65, 118, 105, 100, 97, 103, 111, 115, 32, 50, 48, 49, 49, 32, 65, 118, 105, 100, 97, 103, 111, 115, 32, 82, 101, 100, 32, 40, 68, 111, 117, 114, 111, 41], [80, 111, 114, 116, 117, 103, 97, 108], [80, 111, 114, 116, 117, 103, 117, 101, 115, 101, 32, 82, 101, 100], [49, 53], [82, 111, 103, 101, 114, 32, 86, 111, 115, 115], [56, 55]). 

table([50], [82, 97, 105, 110, 115, 116, 111, 114, 109, 32, 50, 48, 49, 51, 32, 80, 105, 110, 111, 116, 32, 71, 114, 105, 115, 32, 40, 87, 105, 108, 108, 97, 109, 101, 116, 116, 101, 32, 86, 97, 108, 108, 101, 121, 41], [85, 83], [80, 105, 110, 111, 116, 32, 71, 114, 105, 115], [49, 52], [80, 97, 117, 108, 32, 71, 114, 101, 103, 117, 116, 116], [56, 55]).
```

And something like this returns true:

```
?- table("1","Quinta dos Avidagos 2011 Avidagos Red(Douro)","Portugal","Portuguese Red","15","Roger Voss","87"). 
true.
```

And when I try to get a field, this is the result:

```
table("364",X,"US","Pinot Noir","48","Paul Gregutt","95").
X = [87, 105, 110, 100, 101, 114, 108, 101, 97|...] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem. It was a really simple problem, actually.

> Starting with version 7, the syntax for a string object is text
>   between double quotes, such as "hello".

As stated in their documentation before version 7, SWI Prolog didn't accept strings in double quotes. I recently switched down to version 6.6.5 for reasons. So I just worked around this, I used single quotes instead of double quotes and changed all the single quotes in the strings to `.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of a double quoted text in Prolog depends on the standard `double_quotes` flag. The standard specifies three possible values: `codes` (a list of character codes), `atom`, and `chars` (a list of one-character atoms). Some Prolog systems, e.g. SWI-Prolog implement other values such as `string`. You can check the default value of the flag by calling:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(double_quotes, Value).
```

You can set the default flag value using the `set_prolog_flag/2` predicate. You can also set the flag value for the contents of a Prolog file using the `set_prolog_flag/2` directive before the clauses that contain double-quoted terms. for example:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, atom).
```

The most portable flag value is `codes`, which corresponds to the traditional interpretation of double-quoted text.

Comment: The traditional interpretation (Marseille Prolog) is **chars**!